# Shutting down Chromium kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, linux, chromium, kiosk

I'm running an app on arch linux that is using chromium in kiosk mode. There is no keyboard attached as its relying on touch screen, so there isn't a way to 'break out' of chromium to a terminal to shut the computer down that way. So whats the best way to shut the computer down other than just cutting the power supply. I've tried using node to exec a shut down command but without success.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

- SSH into the kiosk and shutdown from there. You will need some way to
  bring the machine back up though - could be either WoL (wake on LAN)
  or physical power button on the machine.
- Press the power button on the machine to shut down - this does
  require physical access though.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to shut down the computer with JavaScript as no such communication exists with the OS.

The best that JavaScript can offer you is to close the Kiosk window with a...

```
 window.parent.close();
```

So if you want to add such a touch button you can use something like this...

```
 <div ontouchstart="window.parent.close();">Close this window</div>
```